# How to use images on the error pages(404, 500 ...)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How to use images on the error pages(404, 500 ...)?

Can I use images from a folder "assets" ?

I need to compile them or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `image` folder within the `public` folder, in the root of your application, and then from there, you can access them by referencing it directly.

An example on the 404 html file.

```
<div class="dialog">
  <div>
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
  </div>
  <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>
  <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

`public/images/` contains the `01.jpg` image file.

Comment: What about a domain that, for whatever reason, doesn't work at all? (for example, because it has been suspended). Storing the images in any directory of the server, even in the root, wouldn't work.

Comment: When I say "server", I mean the hosting space of the domain, not the actual server.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea that you could consider is having the `404.html` and `500.html` located on Amazon S3. Something like that would accomplish you having your picture(s) available on S3 with the entire page itself.

Then if you are using a service like Heroku to host your application, you can change the [`ERROR_PAGE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#configure-your-application) variable to point to your error page on S3.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to store the images anywhere else, you can use Base64 encoding to have the images inside the HTML code of the error page itself. You can use any Base64 encoder such as https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image